# Написать регулярное выражение Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть текст `SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, .. FROM ..`. Хочу его заменить на `SELECT * FROM ..`.
Запрос может быть написан как в одну строку, так и в несколько строк.

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью `REGEXP_REPLACE`.
Почему не работает такой вариант :

```
select regexp_replcace('SELECT COLUMN1 FROM', 'SELECT [.]* FROM', 'SELECT * FROM') from dual;
```

И как написать, чтобы работало?

**UPD**

После ответа Mike пришло осознание, что решать задачу регуляркой в общем виде плохое решение. Регулярка для подобного запроса выглядит страшной и я никогда потом сам не разберусь, что там происходило.

Пример:

```
select column1,
       (select column from table) as column1
  from table1
 union all
  select column1,
       column2
 from table2
```

Comment: Потому, что в потерпел квадратные  скобки лишние.

Comment: без скобок ничего не меняется

Comment: Странно, у меня вот `SELECT .* FROM` отлично все меняет. Точка в квадратных скобках означает именно точку, а не любой символ. А если не работает на более сложных выражениях, может там переводы каретки какие нибудь, которые не входят в определение "точка"

Comment: @mike да, так и есть

Comment: Возможно, я с телефона сейчас не буду проверять. У вас есть уже 2 ответа. Не успел даже комментарий дописать уже опля, как будто боты отвечают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace('SELECT COLUMN1 FROM',
                      'SELECT\W.*\WFROM\W',
                      'SELECT * FROM',1,0,'n')
  from dual
```

В вашем изначальном коде точка в квадратных скобках означает саму себя, а не любой символ. Кроме того точка по умолчанию обозначает "любой символ, кроме перевода каретки", что бы точка начинала обозначать вообще все, что угодно необходим флаг `n` в дополнение к выражению. флаги передаются 6м параметром `regex_replace()`. Так же в флаги может быть полезно добавить `i` что бы выражение работало с любым регистром символов. Что бы выражение воспринимало только отдельно стоящие слова select и from используется `\W` обозначающая любой не алфавитно-числовой символ, включая пробелы, переводы каретки, скобки и т.п.

И к сожалению в совсем общем случае регулярными выражениями заменить не выйдет. Вернее выйдет, но выражение будет ооочень громоздким. потому как для полноценной замены необходим полный синтаксический анализ текста. В данном примере `.*` делает жадный захват, т.е. заменит на `*` все от первого слова SELECT до последнего в предложении слова FROM. Можно сделать его не жадным, но тогда оно будет захватывать строго до первого слова FROM. А в реальной жизни FROM может встречаться как в подзапросах в списке выборки, т.е. до нужной нам точки, так и после нужной точки, в случае если подзапросы встречаются в самом from или последующих частях.

Comment: Понял, что регуляркой вообще не стоит решать мою задачу. Спасибо за это)

Comment: прокомментируйте пожалуйста, что такое `\W` ?

Comment: @lDrakonl Любой не алфавитно-числовой символ.

Answer (score 1):

попробйте так:

```
select 
  regexp_replace('SELECT COLUMN1, '||chr(13)||' COLUMN2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE ...', 
                 'SELECT[\s'||chr(10)||chr(13)||']*.*[\s'||chr(10)||chr(13)||']*FROM[\s'||chr(10)||chr(13)||']*(.*)',
                 'SELECT * FROM \1',
                 1, 0, 'imn')
from dual;
```

Результат:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ...
```

PS данный RegEx не будет работать правильно для случаев на подобие следующего:

```
select column1, (select * from another_table) from mytable;
```

Comment: Для указанного случая работает. В общем случае нет. И еще я так и не понял, что я написал не так изначально)

Comment: @lDrakonl, приведите пожалуйста пример строки, для которой не работает RegEx

Comment: В строках может быть символ переноса строки, на таком примере не работает

Comment: Сейчас не работает даже для написанного вами примера. Возможно дело в том, что у меня Oracle 10

Comment: @lDrakonl, обновил ответ - попробуйте сейчас пожалуйста

Comment: Не совсем правильно. я хочу увидеть все запросы, убрав только вывод колонок.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(

   'SELECT COLUMN1, 
    COLUMN2 FROM MYTABLE;'

, CHR(10), ''), CHR(13), '')    
, '(SELECT ).*( FROM )'
, '\1*\2'
) test 
from dual;
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/ не возражает...

Comment: Не работает в общем случае, когда есть символ переноса строки

Comment: Ну так покажите в вопросе этот самый "общий случай"...

Comment: Обновил вопрос с уточнением. Было не очевидно, что указать на возможность переноса строки надо отдельно. Считал это таким же строковым символом. Исправился

Comment: Задачи заменить все символы переноса не стоит. В любом случае я понял, что регуляркой моя задача решается слишком сложно или вообще не решаеться.

Comment: Да... попробуйте представить коррелированный подзапрос в секции SELECT...